# R writing function not return

Tags: r, function, return

I am new to R, trying to write a function to clean and update dataframe column with condition provided(check if the value in the provided list). The code will work if I hard code with the column names, but will not work when I use the function. There must be something wrong with my function I am not able to find the reasons could someone please help
?

My working code(the survey_2017 dataframe's column "col_1" will update):

```
for (i in 1:length(survey_2017[,"col_1"])) 
{if(survey_2017[,"col_1"][i]%in% yes_no_list[["y"]])
{survey_2017[,"scol_1"][i]<-"y"}
else if (survey_2017[,"col_1"][i]%in% yes_no_list[["n"]])
{survey_2017[,"col_1"][i]<-"n"}
else
survey_2017[,"col_1"][i]<-"na"
}
```

I write a function trying to do the same thing.  after suggestion from thelatemail, it is now working by adding return statements   return (survey_2017[,col_name2])

```
yes_no_update<-function(col_name2){
  for (i in 1:length(survey_2017[,col_name2])) {
    if(survey_2017[,col_name2][i]%in% yes_no_list[["y"]]){survey_2017[,col_name2][i]<-"y"}
    else if (survey_2017[,col_name2][i]%in% yes_no_list[["n"]]){survey_2017[,col_name2][i]<-"n"}
    else
      survey_2017[,col_name2][i]<-"na"
  }
 return (survey_2017[,col_name2])
}
```

after I run the function, it does not perform the column update.(it is working now)

```
yes_no_update("col_1")
```

Comment: You don't have an argument to pass in `survey_2017` or return the changed `survey_2017` from your function. Functions do not change objects in the global workspace.

Comment: thanks so much for pointing out the obvious mistake and guide me to the right direction, it is now working after adding " return (survey_2017[,col_name2])" in my return function.